# Is there a way to add a photo to a Facebook Checkin via their API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm generating a check-in from my app via the checkins api:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

But I dont see any way to attach a photo. Is there an API for that?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to do this?

Comment: I also would like to know if you were able to figure this out. Facebook Checkin api says in Publish_Checkins extended permissions we can attach photos along with checkin but it does not say how.

Comment: anyone find a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a picture bundle, but it only works if you point to a URL, not a byte array. I'm not sure if it's a limitation.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("picture", "http://www.somewhere.com/picture.jpg");
```